# Unix SSL certificates dates are 6 hours more than Windows

Tags: windows, date, openssl, ssl-certificate, utc

I'm having issues with the exactly the same certificate when I'm getting all the data from it. The dates are displayed differently as is displayed in Windows.

In unix I'm doing this command

```
 openssl x509 -noout -in ca.crt -dates
 notBefore=Oct 31 00:00:00 2013 GMT
 notAfter=Oct 30 23:59:59 2023 GMT
```

I open exactly the same certificate in Windows and the dates are displayed as follow:

```
notBefore: ‎Wednesday, ‎October ‎30, ‎2013 6:00:00 PM
notAfter: ‎Monday, ‎October ‎30, ‎2023 5:59:59 PM
```

As you can see the dates does not match.

I'm not sure if is that for the "GMT" timezone or what could be the problem, do you know what's the issue?

Which date could be the correct one? Unix or Windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are correct:

- `openssl` prints the date in **[UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/aboututc.html)** (which is also known/indicated as **"GMT"**)
- Windows prints the date in the system's timezone (whatever timezone that's configured in your Windows machine)

I've seen in your profile that you're from Mexico, so probably your Windows machine is configured with [one of the Mexico's timezones](http://www.timetemperature.com/tzmx/mexico_time_zone.shtml): specifically, one that is 6 hours behind UTC right now (a.k.a. [Central Time Zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_Time_Zone?oldformat=true#Mexico)).